# Why '&&' can use to judge the maximum bound?

Tags: c, max

I don't know what happened to this line `num && *num == maxNum`. Why `var && *var` can be used to judge the max bound?
I really need to someone to explain this...

```
void func(...,size_t *_Nullable num,...){

    size_t num_=0;
    somethingHappen_get_num(&num_);

    if(num){
        *num =  num_;
    }

    if (num && *num == maxNum) { //why???????????
        Log_print("num is too big");
        return Error;
    }
}
```

Comment: num is a pointer, `if(num is not null and num is pointing to a number that is equal to maxNum){do stuff}`

Comment: Thanks! @hanshenrik
'==' priority is bigger than '&&', so I misunderstanding! Your comment let me be clear!!

Comment: It becomes easier to read and self-documenting when the code is written more explicitly: `if ( (num != NULL) && (*num == maxNum) )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since `num` is of `size_t *_Nullable num` i.e pointer type, so you should always check whether its empty i.e `NULL` or have some valid data, if its valid, then only its safe to de reference`(*num)` it.

Here

```
if (num && (*num == maxNum)) { } /* safe & correct, && means if 1st operand is valid then only check 2nd operand which is recommended here */
```

the condition check is correct and safe as first *its checking if `num` is not `NULL`, if that's true then only its checking `*num == maxNum` i.e something is there in `num` so that you can do `*num`*.

Consider below scenario

```
if (num || (*num == maxNum)) { } /* bad practice, don't do it */
```

above condition check creates issue if `num` is `NULL`, due to logical OR operand `||` it will check second operand as first is false and  it causes crash when it perform `*num`.

Comment: @sin Welcome to SO. Feel free to accept answer if it was helpful

Answer (score 2):

You could also write:

```
if ((num != 0) && (*num == maxNum))
```

Maybe this makes it clearer.
First you check if `num` is not `NULL`. If this condition is true (and only then!) you will dereference the pointer and check `*num == maxNum`.